# How to access current element id within if-else conditional statement within Django template tag

Tags: django, django-templates

Hi I have recently started coding in Django. I have the following code-

```
<span class="tooltipButton" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" id="id-{{ dashboard.name }}">
    {{ dashboard.name }}
</span>
```

I want to set the title attribute depending on the element id. So I wrote this -

```
<span class="tooltipButton" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" id="id-{{ dashboard.name }}"
{% if id == "id-Project" %}
    title="Project info"
{% elif id == "id-Admin" %}
    title="Admin info"
{% elif id == "id-Identity" %}
    title="Identity info"
{% elif id == "id-Developer" %}
    title="Developer info"
{% else %}
    title="Tooltip data"
{% endif %}>
    {{ dashboard.name }}
</span>
```

But for some reason it is always going in the else condition even though I am hovering on elements with matching ids. Can someone please help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you want to do is to check for `dashboard.name`.  You can do it like this:

```
<span class="tooltipButton" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" id="id-{{ dashboard.name }}"
{% if dashboard.name == "Project" %}
    title="Project info"
{% elif dashboard.name == "Admin" %}
    title="Admin info"
{% elif dashboard.name == "Identity" %}
    title="Identity info"
{% elif dashboard.name == "Developer" %}
    title="Developer info"
{% else %}
    title="Tooltip data"
{% endif %}>
    {{ dashboard.name }}
</span>
```